# Как определить какое условие выполнено, если в условии несколько вариантов

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Есть условие, в котором расположилось некоторое количество "ИЛИ"

```
if (spec1 == selspec.Text || spec2 == selspec.Text || spec3 == selspec.Text || spec4 == selspec.Text || spec5 == selspec.Text || spec6 == selspec.Text || spec7 == selspec.Text || spec8 == selspec.Text )
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("");
                }
```

Как мне определить какое именно условие было выполнено?

Вроде того как если spec5 подходит под условие, то и нужно в месседже написать, что условие выполненно по spec5. но и при этом, как есть 8 spec, так есть и 8 других переменных (Например "ссс1", "ссс2" итд) и нужно выбрать переменную ссс с тойже цифрой, что была выполнена в условии.

Т.е если spec5 выполнено то нужна переменная ссс5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Если результат должен зависеть от выполненного условия, то и нужно делать отдельную ветку для каждой переменной, а не проверять всё скопом.

```
if (spec1 == selspec.Text) {do ccc1}
else if (spec2 == selspec.Text) {do ccc2}
else if (spec3 == selspec.Text ) {do ccc3}

Итд.
```

Или можно придумать что-нибудь с массивами или словарями, чтобы не писать отдельный код для каждого значения, если вдруг появятся новые случаи.

Например, два массива - один со значениями Text, другой со значениями ccc в том же порядке. В цикле проверять Text, и если совпало, то брать ccc с тем же индексом.

Или switch, если с# позволяет использовать там текст.

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ

Comment: Идея со switch, кстати очень интересная. прям пища для размышлений.